# Call method whenever Class load- Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am struggling to one issue that i want to call one method whenever class load.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandlerAndValidate(): ResponseEntityExceptionHandler(){

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseEntityExceptionHandler::class.java)
        init {
        }
    }

     fun test(){
        println("Always Executed--------->>")
     }
}
```

I want execute test() method -Always, but its not executing.

Comment: When the class is loaded or when the instance is created?

Comment: When class Load...

Comment: Invoke it in constructor or in a companion object

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `test` method inside the companion object, and the call it from the `init` method.

**Example**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandlerAndValidate(): ResponseEntityExceptionHandler(){

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseEntityExceptionHandler::class.java)

        init {
            test()
        }

        fun test(){
            println("Always Executed--------->>")
        }
    }
}
```